# Simple function that returns a Gaussian curve?

Tags: curves, gaussian

> I need a simple function that it's output is a Gaussian for $\mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$.

Any tips? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f_\sigma(x)=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
Here $\sigma$ is controlling the width of the Gaussian